# При деплое рельс капистрано требует судо пароль

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Здарова! Пользуясь вот этим [гайдом](http://codepany.com/blog/rails-5-puma-capistrano-nginx-jungle-upstart/) почти поставил приложение на сервер, но тут капистрано начал требовать судо пароль. Печаль, т.к. консоль капистрано не дает ничего вводить и вопрос "повисает".
Если не в лом, напишите подробно(я нуп), как с этим справиться, пожалуйста.

Comment: Да, к сожалению, в интернете полно плохих гайдов. Отличный пример.

Comment: А хорошие есть? Буду благодарен за ссылку!

Comment: Я в своё время не нашёл. Выяснял по составляющим. Поставил капистрано и на "игрушечном сервере" последовательно ликвидировал то, что мешало и собирал то, чего не хватало. Следующий уровень -- автоматическое развёртывание среды через Ansible или какой-нибудь аналог. В вашем случае нужен беспарольный sudo или изменение процедуры деплоя так, чтобы в sudo не было необходимости.

Comment: А нельзя ли где-то заказать настройку деплоя, не знаете? Вы ведь тоже из СПб.

Comment: Можно, наверное, предложить сисадмину (если у вас есть кто на примете) в качестве разовой подработки. Но такого уровня вещи разработчику полезно уметь делать самому. Разобраться самостоятельно очень даже реально, но может быть небыстро.

Comment: Нет, сисадмина с руби у меня нет. Я думал, Вы кого-то можете порекомендовать. Мне просто нужно как можно быстрее разместить для одной фирмы сайт визитку, а потом я смогу уже поучиться спокойно.

Comment: А, если вы прям весь деплой хотите настроить, с написанием Capistrano'вских файлов... это да, вам уже не админ, в рубист-девопс нужен, или около того. Ну, мораль сей басни: не беритесь за срочные вещи, которые пока не умеете делать. Сейчас вам достаточно разобраться с беспарольным sudo, причём так, чтобы сервер не стал доступен всем желающим для эксплуатации :Р